# Using REST api for my application

Tags: javascript, java, rest, jsp

So, I am trying a very simple CRUD application. Front is in JSP with javascript and it sends the information to the servlet using doPost() so I wanted to know how do I use REST api in it. I want to For example once submitting the form to the java page how do I stay at the form page itself and have the information send to the database which is connected to the servlet.?

Comment: You can use [jquery post](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yysylQFkhhk).

Comment: You should learn about Asynchronous Request, or AJAX. As @jordaniac89 mentioned, JQuery AJAX is very useful.